# element.valueAsDate = xxx -- not working any more... (javascript)

Tags: javascript, exception, dom

In my application i have a javascript that sets the default values for certain dates. The function that does this looks like this:

```
<script language='javascript'> 
setNow(document.getElementById('date_86')); //line 166
setNow(document.getElementById('time_86'));
setNow(document.getElementById('date_0'));
setNow(document.getElementById('time_0'));

    function setNow(element) { //line 173
        date = new Date();date.setHours(date.getHours() + 3);
        element.valueAsDate = date;
    }
...
</script>
```

html:

```
<input type='date' id='date_86' name='date_86' />
```

The funny thing is that until quite recently it used to work, but now it doesn't, and Chrome's console says:

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
setNowmanual.html:173
(anonymous function)manual.html:166
```

I can't really see why setNow is not an object in this DOM, if I understand the meaning of this correctly.

**PS**: Happens the same thing when i swap the declaration and the call, only the line numbers are different in the console report.

Comment: Can you show us some HTML as well?

Comment: Side note: if you are using HTML5, you should change `<script language='javascript'>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`. The `language` attribute was already deprecated in HTML4.

Comment: @TimVermaelen: The page in question is quite large, which parts would be relevant? The elements that are passed as arguments to the setNow() function are declared as <input type='date' id='date_86' name='date_86' />

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Why exactly is it wrong? The calls to the whole form and the calls to that function are generated by the server-side script, and when there is a date on the server side, it is inserted as the value, when it is null, it is generated by the javascript.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I did change the javascript's openning tag to <script type="text/javascript"> -- didn't help either.

Comment: I'm really curious about the values you're passing along but I assume they're just numbers?

Comment: @Ibolit - You didn't get the point. I just said that, as a general rule, you need to care about HTML quality as well. Doing DOM manipulations on invalid HTML can lead to unexpected results and cross-browser issues. I didn't pretend to fix your current problem.

Answer (score 6):

**Bloody hell!**
A quotation from Chromium blog ([source](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/browse_thread/thread/d1a22c42ebdf8ee4/9eb4210ce60341b1))

> Hi everyone,  We disabled the following input types, and Google Chrome
>   16 isn't going to  have them. 
>        *date, datetime, datetime-local, month, time*, and *week*.  These types have had simple textfield interfaces with spin buttons. Since 
>   Google Chrome 16,  they are not recognized as valid input types, and
>   work as type=text.  They were disabled because of their
>   incompleteness.  Their user-interfaces  were not satisfying,  and the
>   existence of these types were harmfull for feature detection.  We'll
>   enable them again when we complete to implement their rich 
>   user-interfaces. 
>   --  TAMURA, Kent  Software Engineer, Google

Comment: It would be nice if they'd removed them in a way that didn't break existing code. Oh well.

Comment: For future reference, this seems not intended to work at all! Looks like a massive gap in the spec to me. Why would a date-specific property not be available on a date field?! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625316#c9 So forget `valueAsDate` and do your own thing, like in the good old days of IE6.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: According to what I just read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html that error will be thrown if you try to set `valueAsDate` on a control that "isn't date- or time-based", but given that your input is `type="date"` I'm not sure what's going on.

EDIT 2: According to this page: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/browse_thread/thread/d1a22c42ebdf8ee4/9eb4210ce60341b1 Chrome version 16 has disabled the date and time input types and they will be treated as text.

<s>Chrome doesn't seem to like the dot syntax for custom properties/attributes. Use `.setAttribute()` instead:</s>

```
// Chrome doesn't like
element.valueAsDate = date;

// So do this:
element.setAttribute("valueAsDate",date);

// And to retrieve the value:
var v = element.getAttribute("valueAsDate")
```

Comment: An unexplained downvote? Thanks for nothing whoever you are. I ran the code exactly as given in the question and got the same error, but when I used `setAttribute()` instead the error went away. I've noticed similar behaviour in other situations. I think that's justification enough for my answer.

Comment: It's not a syntax thing, they are entirely different things. Custom properties don't cause any errors in chrome, and attribute values can only be strings. So when you do setAttribute.. the date object is lost. On top of this, valueAsDate is not a custom property. But I downvoted for the typical property/attribute ignorance anyway ;P

Comment: OK, thanks @Esailija. I don't mind downvotes when I'm wrong, I just don't like downvotes without explanation. I've now realised that `valueAsDate` isn't actually a custom property: turns out to be an HTML5 property I just hadn't used before. So on the one hand my answer does make the error go away, but on the other hand it isn't really solving the problem. Sorry.

Comment: Well, that seems plausible, because my inputs turned into something that looks like a normal (type='text') rather than time or date (with little arrows) inputs. But why could _that_ be? (It probably happened after Chrome autoupdated, but how to fix that?)

Comment: I gave up trying to find official Chrome release notes for the latest version, but I'm running version 16 and I did find a note (see my edited answer) that support for the date and time types has been (temporarily) removed in version 16.