# Javascript: getHours() returning wrong datum

Tags: javascript, html, time

JS: extracting hours same as inserted into `<input type='time' id='arrive'></input>` tag.

I'm trying to parse the time from an input field, I tought that I could use `document.getElementbyId('arrive').valueAsDate.getHours()` property to get only the hour

Now if I enter '23' the property I read is '0', if I enter '10' the property I read is '11'.

How could I extract the value entered unmodified? (ex: I put '7' in and I read '7')

Comment: That returns a string, I want that string (already) parsed... I don't like to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @randomSoul [`valueAsDate` return the value interpreted as `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: @DDS does this apply? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8643433/4642943

Comment: @randomSoul it's a [property on an HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) that gives you the value parsed as a date. Scroll down - it's the fourth from the very bottom.

Comment: @Tobsta No, I don't think so:  in my case it gives a 'real' result, does not throw an exception

Comment: `valueAsDate` returns `Fri Jan 02 1970 00:11:00 GMT+0100 (Greenwich Mean Time)` on a `time` input.

Comment: use getUTCHours instead

Comment: It works, it looks 'time' field interprets its input as UTC time

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementbyId('arrive').valueAsDate.getHours()
```

The above code will give you always in `UTC`, 
So to get time for your Geo-location you have to convert into according to your local standard time.Like  for INDIA +5:30.

```
t = new Date(document.getElementById("arrive").valueAsDate);
tt = new Date(t.getTime() + t.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
....
....
hh = tt.getHous();
mm = tt.getMinuts();
```

Hope it works for you..

Comment: I converted like this: `document.getElementbyId('arrive').valueAsDate.getHours() + document.getElementbyId('arrive').valueAsDate.getTimezoneOffset()` UTC was 'ok' by the code but was semantically wrong (I think)