# React render date input element with valueAsDate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the value of an input `type=date` in React and I'm looking for a way to use `valueAsDate` and set it to a date object, is there any way to do that?

P.S. I know there are other ways to set the value but my question is specifically about `valueAsDate`.

Comment: What is valueAsDate?

Comment: seems to be [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642921/element-valueasdate-xxx-not-working-any-more-javascript)

Comment: @fubar Chromium blog in 2011 referring to input type=date: _They were disabled because of their incompleteness._  It was since added back I guess [see link to caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=Date%20inp)

Comment: @DmitryReutov Its a proeprty on input type date, and you can set it like this: `input.valueAsDate = new Date()`

Answer (score 2):

According to [this open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11369) in the React GitHub, this feature is not currently available in React, so the answer to your question is no.